# PC health minimum requirements for updating to windows 11

Tags: windows-10

After taking a few steps i was able to get all green in the PC health check app. However, the windows update page in the settings still reports an error. I don't see any way to proceed.

[image]

Comment: Define "taking a few steps." Does the PC actually meet requirements?

Comment: Run [WhyNotWin11](https://github.com/rcmaehl/WhyNotWin11) and it will tell you what's missing.

Comment: If you have all green, download the Windows 11 ISO (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows11) and run Setup on the ISO.

Comment: “After taking a few steps ….” - What steps? Be specific and detailed